# what is this component how i can create it in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to know about this component in android and how I can create it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called image slider . Follow below link for learning how to do it

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: Can you please explain why i was down voted? @who did vote down